# Representing $j_*\mathcal{O}_U$ as filtered colimit of perfect complexes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a quasi-compact and quasi-separated scheme, and $U\subseteq X$ be a quasi-compact open subscheme. Then we can consider $Rj_*\mathcal{O}_U$ the (derived) pushforward of the structure sheaf of $U$. This is a coconnective sheaf of rings (in fact it is locally of Tor amplitude in $(-∞,0]$, since locally it can be represented as a finite limit of sheaves of the form $\mathcal{O}_X[f^{-1}]$).

> **Q:** Can $Rj_*\mathcal{O}_U$ be represented as a filtered colimit of *uniformly bounded above* perfect complexes?

*Note:* I am using the homological grading convention, so, e.g., for me every connective sheaf is bounded below.

The result is true if $X$ has an ample family of line bundles, because then I could just use the colimit of Koszul complexes, but I'd like it to be true in more generality.

Comment: I am not sure how useful it is, but you can try the following standard construction. Let $\tilde{X}$ be the blowup of the complement of $U$ in $X$. Then the map $j$ decomposes as $\pi \circ i$, where $i \colon U \to \tilde{X}$ and $\pi$ is the blowup. The point is that $i$ is affine, so $Ri_* = i_*$, and $\pi$ is projective, so you can use a relative Cech complex to compute $R\pi_*$.

Comment: @DenisNardin $p_*$ does not preserve perfect complexes under further hypotheses (finite Tor-amplitude, or domain and codomain regular). If you can choose $i$ to be a regular immersion (I guess this should be possible but not sure without checking) then the projection of the blowing up would be lci so that would suffice.

Comment: @crystalline Ugh.. I misunderstood theorem 2.5.4 in Thomason-Trobaugh

Comment: I mistyped (you understood but just to clarify), I meant it does not preserve perfect complexes *without* further hypotheses

Comment: @crystalline It seems to me that if I manage to prove that $R\pi_*\mathcal{O}$ is perfect, the proof is complete though (since $U$ is an effective Cartier divisor in $\tilde X$). Do you agree?